# EHWIC-1GE-SFP for Cisco 1941

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-commands, interface, cisco-isr

I was able to configure the interface but only the GE port is working, not the SFP port.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change to the SFP interface. Under the interface configuration, configure:

```
media-type sfp
```

To change back to the copper interface:

```
media-type rj45
```